# Wordpress Generate Attachment Metadata not working

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to insert posts automatically to wordpress. Posts i posted is very well but somehow i can't generate metadatas for thumbnails.

Here is my code for metadatas

```
          $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $thumb ), null );

      $bol = explode('/', $thumb);

      $fileur = $bol[count($bol)-1];


      $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();


      $tits = $wp_upload_dir['path'].'/'.basename($thumb);


      $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

      $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $thumb ), 
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $thumb ) ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
      );


      $attachment_id=wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $tits, $post_id);



      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
      $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $tits );

      wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
      set_post_thumbnail($post_id,$attachment_id);
```

I read all the connected questions on community but it doesnt helped my issue. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

According to this WP wiki page: [wp_insert_attachment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) you must use unchanged file path from upload dir for these functions: **wp_insert_attachment**, **wp_generate_attachment_metadata**

In your codebase, I see that you're doing something wrong with your $thumb like extracting its basename and building a new path that lives in $tits. I am 99% sure that the problem is of wrong file path.

Comment: Dear Andy, thank you for answering and helping me out. But i tried to use get_attached_file function but it gives me same response.

Comment: Could you provide what got those guys: $thub, $tits, $attachment_id and $attach_data  from your example ?

Comment: Hello Andy, $thumb is a image file which is downloaded to wp-content/uploads/12 with php cURL, $tits is full path to image file and $attachment_id is thumbnail attached to post but unfortunetly $attach_data returns empty array every single time

Comment: I have a hunch that you should try to use $thumb instead of $tits

Comment: $thumb is a url to image file. i download it with php cURL

Comment: Hold on, what is `$attach_id` ? I see only this one: `$attachment_id`. Please correct me in case Im wrong.

Comment: Andy you are number one my friend. I cant believe i made such a dumb mistake like that. Sorry for bothering and again god bless you!